# CLAuthorizationStatus AuthorizedWhenInUse called only for the first time

Tags: swift, ios8, cllocationmanager

Here's a problem if I don't request "AuthorizedWhenInUse" status once my app first view controller is loaded I'll never get update after.

Let's say I have a map view controller. When I ask for status in the `viewDidLoad` method it updates my location, i.e. `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)` is called.

Now I added an intro view controller, once user finishes intro he/she is going to the old map controller. But now `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)` isn't called anymore!

What I noticed is if I go to settings and toggle authorization status manually for my application and then get back to my app the `didUpdateLocations` is called.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
        locationManager.delegate = self
        // >=iOS8
        if (locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"))) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
            println("User's location: \(location.description)")
        } else {
            println("User's location is unknown")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues with what you posted, here are just two:

1. You are calling `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` from `viewDidLoad` this will only fire if the view is not already loaded into memory. Recommend moving this into `viewWillAppear` so it fires every time.
2. This code should be rewritten:

   ```
       if (locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"))) {
           locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
       } else {
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       }
   ```

You need to check the `authorizationStatus` instead, if it is `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` then request permission using the if statement you have above.  If you don't iOS 8 users will always drop into the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` section. You don't want that because the OS will only ask for permission once. It will not ask again unless you rest your phones Location Privacy under Settings.

Comment: What helped is I added an "if" statement as you suggested above. The only addition is if status equals to `CLAuthorizationStatus. AuthorizedWhenInUse` I call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`